# Django query an object only if all ManyToMany fields match dict

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-models, django-q

I am attempting to create a screener test where the user is matched only with `programs` for which they meet all requirements. The user's input is a dictionary, for example:

```
user_dict = [{location: CA, gender: male, skill: crafts}]
```

The `programs` have `requirements` as shown in the models below:

```
class Program(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    requirements = models.ManyToManyField("Requirement")
class Requirement(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    status = models.CharField()
```

I would like the query to retrieve all `programs` for which all their associated `requirements` are met. For example, if a `program` called `camp counselor` only has the following 2 requirements associated with it:

```
[{'name': 'location', 'status': 'CA'}, {'name': 'skill', 'status': crafts}]
```

It will be retrieved because all of its `requirements` match the user's dictionary.  It there were a 3rd `requirement`:

```
[{'name': 'gender', 'status': 'female'}]
```

Then it would not be retrieved. However, if that 3rd `requirement`'s `status` were `male`, it would match and be retrieved.

Currently, I am iterating through each `program` and checking if there is a match, but I feel like there must be a better way to execute this:

```
for p in program:
    for r in p.requirements.all():
        if user_dict[r.name] == r.status:
            print "Match"
        else:
            print "No Match"
```

Comment: Do you need to get all program matching to requirements?

Comment: Yes, I need to retrieve all programs for which `requirements` are fully met

Comment: Is it a list of dictionaries? I mean `user_dict`?

Comment: No just a single dictionary with various attributes obtained through a screener (ie gender, skill, location)

Comment: Please check my answer if it provides you what you are going to do. Left your comment if there any questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single dict like:

```
user_dict = {'location': 'CA', 'gender': 'male', 'skill': 'crafts'}
```

You can query all Programs with a query:

```
from django.db.models import Q 

query = Q()
for key, value in user_dict.items():
    query |= Q(**{'requirements__name': key, 'requirements__status': value})    
Program.objects.filter(query)
```

If we uncover query above will be like:

```
Q(requirements__name='location', requirements__status='CA') |
Q(requirements__name='gender', requirements__status='male') |
Q(requirements__name='skill', requirements__status='crafts')
```

So it will return all Programs which have any of those above `Requirements`.

Comment: Will this also include a `program` that does not require all 3 of the attributes listed in this particular `user_dict` (ie its only requirements are `{'location': 'CA', 'skill': 'crafts'}`)? Alternatively, does it exclude `programs` that list additional `requirement`s that are not keys in `user_dict` (ie `{'education': 'masters'}`)?

Comment: It will return if any of those Requirements is connected with Program. In case you add key that doesn't exist as attribute of Requirements you will have an error.

Comment: Is it possible to start with each `program` and only return those for which all their associated `requirements` are met by the `user_dict`?

Comment: Do you mean that Program that is related with at least 3 Requirements that are listed in your dictionary?

Comment: The only thing that matters is that the `requirements` associated with all the `program`s returned are satisfied by the `user_dict`. Other than that, it doesn't matter what other data is included in the `user_dict`.